# ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a program where a user enters four numbers using regular expressions . If one of those numbers is 13 then the numbers to the left do not count toward the sum. My problem is creating an exception where none of the numbers equal 13. I cant seem to find a regular expression for my exception

```
puts "enter a number then hit enter four times"

number1 = STDIN.gets

number2 = STDIN.gets
number3 = STDIN.gets

number4 = STDIN.gets


if number1 =~ /13/ then
  puts number2.to_i + number3.to_i + number4.to_i
end

if number2 =~/13/ then
  puts number3.to_i + number4.to_i
end

if number3 =~/13/ then
  puts number4.to_i
 if number4 =~/13/ then
   puts "0"
 end
 if number1 != 13 or number2 != 13 or number3 != 13 or number4 != 13
   puts number1.to_i + number2.to_i + number3.to_i + number4.to_i
 end
end
```

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - that's a nice polite reminder message - is it OK if i copy to use as template?  i.e, then it will be easy with autohotkey etc, whenever it's needed

Comment: @Adel No problem at all! I have a bunch of SO comment templates that I've made saved as snippets, since I think having the links is best and I don't want to find them every time `:)`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - Thank You So Much! Yes, I will make a template-collection too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions, it should be mentioned that the following logic will yield true for more than just 13.  It will also match 413, 131, 941771341, ...

```
if number1 =~ /13/ then
```

Changing it to `if number =~ /^13$/ then` would be more accurate, but not as good as using to `to_i`.

The other line in question...

```
if number1 != 13 or number2 != 13 or number3 != 13 or number4 != 13
```

...doesn't work as expected because you are comparing a string to a number, and the logic join should be `and`.  Comparing it to "13" won't work either, since it is actually "13\n".  You can use `number1.to_i != 13 and number2.to_i != 13` or something like `number1 !~ /^13$/ and number2 !~ /^13$/ ...`  You could also figure out where to use an `else` statement in there.

I really recommend studying the other answers though.  They are far more elegant and Rubyesque.

Answer (score 6):

I don't mean to rewrite your whole logic but you could use the enumerable module and do something like

```
puts "enter a number then hit enter four times"

# Collect 4 numbers
numbers = 4.times.map{ STDIN.gets }.reverse

# Take the numbers until the first 13, then sum them
puts numbers.map(&:to_i).take_while{ |a| a != 13 }.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: Why not `4.times do ... end`?

Comment: No worries! Just a helpful suggestion `:)`.

Comment: Or while we're having fun: `numbers = 4.times.map{ STDIN.gets }` :)

Comment: @Phrogz Interesting that `4.times` becomes an array when iterated like that (though I guess I shouldn't be surprised, since it's an enumerator, just is semantically unexpected I suppose). If doing that I'd usually opt for `(1..4).map` since it seems more obvious that I'm giving `map` a collection to start.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall FWIW, `times` without a block actually returns an Enumerator (as does `upto` and `step`).

Answer (score 2):

gmalette, that's really interesting syntax.  I learned from it.  However, you're code needs to have the take_while method count backwards from the end of the array.  Also, the reduce method will add the stings together.  So "44" + "55" = "4455".  This works:

```
puts "Enter four numbers separated by spaces:"
numbers = STDIN.gets.split
numbers.reverse!.collect! {|s| s.to_i }
puts numbers.take_while{ |a| a != 13 }.reduce(:+)
```

That reduce statement is really interesting.

Comment: Also, you can shorthand the collect (map) method with the &:to_i like in my answer

Comment: gmalette, you give the most "rubyish" answers, I've ever seen.  :)